# Optimize CoffeeScript-generated JS for V8

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

`coffee`-generated JS of the following simple code snippet:

```coffee
console.log 'b' if 'b' in arr
```

is

```js
var __indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) {
    for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (i in this && this[i] === item) return i;
    } return -1;
};

if (__indexOf.call(arr, 'b') >= 0) {
  console.log('b');
}
```

I can understand why it is so. IE doesn't support `indexOf`, and we want to make sure our CS code runs smoothly on *all* browsers. But, when writing the code for a Node.js server, we know *exactly* what the JS engine supports ([ECMA-262, 5th edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf)), so we wouldn't need the above trick.

I'm not terribly familiar with different JavaScript implementations, but I'm sure it's not the only non-optimal code `coffee -c` produces because of browser incompatibilities, and if we consider all of them in a production server with thousands of concurrent connections, they add a considerable unnecessary overhead to the code.

Is there a way to remedy this? More and more Node.js code is written in CS these days, and with SourceMap on the horizon, the number would be even greater...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is barely non-optimal; the `__indexOf` declaration is evaluated once, at the beginning, and it's immediately resolved to `[].indexOf`, i.e. using the underlying implementation's `Array.prototype.indexOf`.  That's not exactly a huge expense, surely.

I'd need to see some other examples of "non-optimal" code, but I'm sure most of them fall into the same basket. Number of concurrent connections doesn't scale the effect of this at all.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not really familiar with how JS interpreters work under the hood, and didn't know that the above resolution needs to be done only once. I guess it has  something to do with JS being prorotype-based... In that case, you're right that it's really a non-isuue and doesn't scale.

Comment: It's not that it's prototype-based, but rather the assignment `__indexOf = [].indexOf || …` will only happen once—when the assignment is executed. At any rate, there's unlikely to be any perf difference between `__indexOf.call(x, y)` and `x.indexOf(y)`—in fact, I'd imagine the former might be *faster*, because it doesn't require looking up in `x`'s prototype chain (!). So, if anything, CoffeeScript is giving you an optimisation. :)